# Incrementing value pointed to by int* from struct*

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct defined like so:

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int* numVotes;
} candidate;
```

Allocated like so:

```
 candidate* Person[10]; 
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    Person[i] = malloc(sizeof(candidate));
    Person[i]->name = malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    Person[i]->numVotes = malloc(sizeof(int));
 }
```

Trying to increment value stored in numVotes like so:

```
int v;
  scanf("%d",&v);
  while (v != 0) {
    switch (v) { 
      case 1 : 
        Person[0]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 2 : 
        Person[1]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 3 : 
        Person[2]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 4 : 
        Person[3]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 5 : 
        Person[4]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 6 : 
        Person[5]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 7 : 
        Person[6]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 8 : 
        Person[7]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 9 : 
        Person[8]->numVotes++;
        break;
      case 10 : 
        Person[9]->numVotes++;
        break;
      default :
        printf("Spoiled vote\n");
        break;

    }
    scanf("%d",&v);
  }
```

However when printing the results I believe this is incrementing the memory address pointed to by numVotes. In addition, it gives me invalid pointer when trying to free the memory. How can I increment only the value (not the memory address) pointed to by Person[i]->numVotes? Thank you.

Comment: just use `int numVotes`, don't declare a pointer on an integer when you only need 1 integer (and don't `malloc` it either)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: You know what they say. When you learn to use a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: Hint: how would your code look like if there were 100 candidates instead of 10 ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: you could always create a bash script to generate the 100 `case` expressions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that you shouldn't use *int and you should use int . 
But if you must

```
++(*Person[2]->numVotes);
....
printf(%d, *Person[2]->numVotes);
```

also it seems you forgot to zero initialize you will get garbage values always so add

```
memset(Person[i]->numVotes , 0, sizeof (int));
```

in your for loop

Comment: Because of the parenthesis dereferencing work first so I don't believe it will be a problem. It is not important here but  it is a good habit use pre-increment operator than post -increment when possible. Since post-increment increases than returns a copy which may have perf effect in big objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `int numVotes`, don't declare a pointer on an integer when you only need 1 integer. You're incrementing the pointer here.

BTW your data is globally static so you could write all your code without pointers:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[25];
    int numVotes;
} candidate;
```

"allocation" (BTW this also initializes the value of `numVotes`, this is required or your `numVotes` value will be bogus):

```
 candidate Person[10]; 
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < sizeof(Person)/sizeof(candidate); i++) { 
    Person[i].numVotes = 0;
 }
```

then in your interactive loop (which could be reduced drastically because there's no need for a `case` here!) just do:

```
while(1)
{
 // expect 1 => 10 or 0 to stop
 scanf("%d",&v);
 if (v==0) break;
 v--;
 if ((v>=0) && (v<(int)sizeof(Person)/sizeof(candidate))
 {
   Person[v].numVotes++;
 }
 else
 {
   printf("spoiled vote\n");
 }
}
```